# Array is not is not iterable in TypeScript to JS

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have such error

```
D:\MyProject\Microservice\microservice\dist\main.js:665
            ...commands_1.POST_COMMANDS_HANDLERS,
                          ^
TypeError: commands_1.POST_COMMANDS_HANDLERS is not iterable
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\MyProject\Microservice\microservice\dist\main.js:665:27)
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\MyProject\Microservice\microservice\dist\main.js:1677:42)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\MyProject\Microservice\microservice\dist\main.js:617:14)
```

It occurs when TypeScript code is translated into JS. Below is this piece of code in TypeScript

```
@Module({
  imports: [CqrsModule, TypeOrmModule.forFeature([PostEntity])],
  providers: [
    ...POST_COMMANDS_HANDLERS,
    ...POST_QUERIES_HANDLERS,
    ...POST_EVENT_HANDLERS,
    {
```

POST_COMMAND_HANDLERS:

```
export const POST_COMMANDS_HANDLERS: Type<ICommandHandler>[] = [
  CreatePostCommandHandler,
  UpdatePostCommandHandler,
  DeletePostCommandHandler,
];
```

POST_COMMANDS_HANDLERS variable is an array, why can't it iterate?

My tsconfig.ts

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "ES2021",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
    "paths": {
      "@lib/providers": [
             /*my libs*/
  }
}
```

Representing my module in JS code

```
exports.PostModule = PostModule = __decorate([
    (0, common_1.Module)({
        imports: [cqrs_1.CqrsModule, typeorm_1.TypeOrmModule.forFeature([entities_1.PostEntity])],
        providers: [
            ...commands_1.POST_COMMANDS_HANDLERS,
            ...queries_1.POST_QUERIES_HANDLERS,
            ...events_1.POST_EVENT_HANDLERS,
            {
```

Comment: What is your tsconfig?

Comment: Please show more of main.js. It's not clear what `commands_1` is, or if it's actually referring to what you think it should. It appears you're using webpack, which has its own intricacies. Please try and create a [mre] of the issue.

Comment: Added my tsconfig to the question

Comment: You should be using ESM to avoid TypeScript messing up wildcard imports like this. `"module": "esnext"` and add "type": "module"` to package.json

Comment: I did as you said, added `"type": "module"` to package.json and `"module": "esnext"` to tsconfig. Now he can't find modules at all, here's an example: `Cannot find module '@nestjs/core'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'nodenext', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option?`